# How many times does this recursive function iterate?

Tags: recursion, iteration, proof

I have a recursive function, as follows, where b >= 0

```
def multiply(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    elif b % 2 == 0:
        return multiply(2*a, b/2)
    else:
        return a + multiply(a, b-1)
```

I would like to know how many times the function will run **in terms of a and b**.
Thanks.

Comment: That method looks broken. Try `multiply(1, 0)`, for example, and you'll have an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Hint: use binary representation of b and check value used in next multiply() call.

Answer (score 1):

If binary representation of b (call it B) ends with 1, like xxxx1 than next call to multiply has B = xxxx0.

If B ends with 0, like xxxx0 than next value of B is xxxx.

With that, digit of binary representation of b adds one call if it is 0, and two calls if it is 1. Summing that total number of calls equals to `length of initial B + number of ones in initial B`.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I think your function does not work the way you intend it. In recursion the most important thing as a propper ending criteria, since it will run forever elseways.

Now your ending criteria is `a==0`, but with each recursive call you do not decrease a. Just make a pen & paper simulation with a=5 and check if it would stop at any point.

Comment: Sorry, I realised I made a typo in the base case. I updated it.

Comment: You figured it out?

Comment: At work right now, might have time to give it a look in the evening. But I think you can do it yourself, too! Try using an algorithmic approach to solve the recurrence. 
This could be very helpful I think: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do it :/ Maths not my strong point